# How to realize a notification system like Facebook?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I wanted to do a Facebook-similiar notifiaction system, but I just can't think of the way, how to realize it.

I read here about various opinions like having one table for it, others says to have two.

However I'm trying the most effecient way with only neccesarry data entries.
This is my `notfication` table so far:
id, uid, type, read (boolean), date.

So I thought of one example:

Insert a comment, call notification function that inserts my uid (user_id), type (comment, like, etc), read='1', NOW().

I set read to 1, because I don't want to get notified when I'm posting something. Then I thought I'll update `notification` by setting read to 0 by all other users, because they haven't read this new post yet.

But now I'm thinking of another post that will be made 5sec later or something. Then all other `read` entries are set to 0 again, which is right, but in this scenario I can't think of displaying (SELECT) the right results for each single user.
Because it isn't specified which user missed which new notification(s).

I hope you could follow me and have any suggestions. If I'm doing it the wrong way in general I'd also appreciate advices.

Comment: Now, I ask you, how would you find out how I know you using SQL?  How would you be able to figure out how I know Keven Bacon in SQL?  Furthermore, how would you do this in any efficient manner? The answer is: not easily. http://blog.alagad.com/2010/07/13/a-quick-overview-of-graphing-databases/

Answer (score 5):

First, you have to know if your notifications are broad casted to all your uses or can be user specific. In case of Facebook,  I would say it's the second option.

My first recommendation, is to find an open-source project (or may be even 2) that implement this feature and look at their code.

My second recommendation, is to write down all the requirements for this feature, as often, a small restriction can induce a modification on the table structure or even an addition of a new table (For example, can a notification be sent to multiple users at once? can a user send a notification to another user?...).

Here's the way I would go, using 2 tables, one for the message and one for the NtoN relation with users:
**Table Notification**

```
ID // auto increment ID
sender_id // Can be a subsystem or another user. To be defined / optional. Does not have to be a foreign key.
title // Title of the notification
body // The text message
type // warning, message, error or any notification class you can think of
... // you can add other options, like priority, attachment...
```

**Table Notification_User**

```
notification_id // Foreign Key for the notification
receiver_id // Foreign Key for the user
is_read // is the notification read
is_deleted // is the notification deleted, this implements a Trash bin like feature
created_at // time at which the notification was sent
read_at // time at which the notification was read
deleted_at // Time at which the notification was deleted
```

Comment: I agree with the recommendations made by this answer. However depending upon the load you may want to look into queueing technologies such as Rabbitmq for queueing and broadcasting the notifications as opposed to the database. Further you may want to look at implementations such as the Observer or Signals and Slots to listen and register the various actions performed by the user or the system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm kinda working on that, but I've a question about "When happens what?". i.e. I want to post a comment somewhere, I've currently a code that checks: is there an entry in `notification`? If not, make one (insert site, type, my user_id). If there is one, insert into `notification_user` (notification id, my user_id, is_read (= 0 ?), created, read_at). So this is the point where I'm confused... when and how do I realize to show other users an new entry have been made? Is it smart that this notification table is assigned to each user?

Comment: And shouldn't be `is_read` always be 0? Just for clarification.

Comment: Let's say, the notification is not assigned to each user. What happens if user A reads the notification but not user B? how will you set the is_read value? This value has to be per user, otherwise, if one reads it, the read value will be set to true for all the other uses, whether they missed it or not. Which is not the ideal I think.

Comment: As to how you realize a new entry has been made: When a user log in, you run a select request on the Notification_user where is_read is false. When the user click on the message title, you show the message body and set the is_read value to true. This way, the notification is correctly set as read and the user won't be notified again on his next login.

Comment: is_read tells you if a user was notified or not. It should be 0 when the notification is sent, and 1 once the user reads it.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest having a notification table with columns (notification_id and notification_msg and create_date) where you store all notifications. Then have another table notification_user with columns (userid, notificationid, read) where you store all userids with the notification ids. 
So if you have say one notification for 1000 users, you store the message in the first table and then store the 1000 users' ids and the notification ids in the second table. That way you can easily track when a user has read a particular notification and set read to 1.